# Getting Blank Emails with PHPmailer

Tags: php, email

I have created this form in the home page of my website -

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
<p>Name:</p> <input type="text" name="name" size="40">
<p>Email:</p> <input type="email" name="email" size="40">
<p>Subject:</p> <input type="text" name="subject" size="40">
<p>Message: </p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="41"></textarea>
<p><input type="submit" value="Contact Us"></p>
</form>
```

Now i have pasted the below code in the mail.php file Note I am also using phpmailer ..

```
<?php
require '/home/hostiojv/public_html/verticaldesign.net/FinalComeagain/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'p3XXXX.prod.phx3.secureXXXX.net';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'reply@example.com';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'XXXX';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;


$mail->From = 'reply@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'John Smith';
$mail->AddAddress('info@example.com');               // Name is optional

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
header("Location: http://verticaldesign.net/FinalComeagain/index.html");
?>
```

I am new in PHP and also I understand the fact that I am not defining the Subject or failing to capture the email address from the Home page of the website.

Note: I am getting emails but they contain this - "This is the Message Body in Bold" and also i am not getting the email id that i am adding in the contact form.

Also I am not sure what to add here - $mail->AddAddress('info@example.com');
so i had created another email apart from reply@example.com..

let me know what I am doing wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the capture variables to your `$mail` object.

```
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->Subject = $subject;
```

Comment: I have no idea how to say you thank you for this :D you just saved my day

Comment: @danishdeb No worries, glad to help.